# Context sensitivity in commentstring

Tags: vim, folding

When setting folds manually, it would be handy if it were possible to set the `commentstring` in a context sensitive manner.  Consider the case in which the language uses BCPL-style comment markers (i.e., comments begin with `//` and are terminated by a newline), the first line of the visual block contains a comment, and the last line does not.  Currently, if `commentstring` is set to `//%s`, redundant `//` characters will be appended to the first line when `zf` is used to create a fold.

Is it possible to set `commentstring` so that the `//` characters are added only if they do not already appear on the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `:help fold-create-marker`, automatic folding marker insertion
does not work properly when:

> - The line already contains a marker with a level number.  Vim then doesn't
>     know what to do.
> - Folds nearby use a level number in their marker which gets in the way.
> - The line is inside a comment, `commentstring` isn't empty and nested
>     comments don't work.  For example with C: adding `/* {{{ */` inside
>     a comment will truncate the existing comment.

Thus, it is not possible to change the default `zf` behavior by modifying the
`commentstring` setting.

However, it is possible to create a custom version of the `zf` command that
would take into consideration that starting or ending (or both) lines of
a fold could have comments.  For example, consider the following mappings, one
for marking a fold by visual selection, another for using with a motion
command.

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>zf :set opfunc=CreateMarkerFold<cr>g@
vnoremap <silent> <leader>zf :<c-u>call CreateMarkerFold(visualmode(), 1)<cr>
function! CreateMarkerFold(vt, ...)
    let range = map(['[<', ']>'], 'line("''".v:val[a:0])')
    let mark = split(&foldmarker, ',')
    let pat = escape(&commentstring, '\')
    let pat = '\V' . substitute(pat, '\\\@<!%s', '\\zs\\ze\\.\\{-}', '')
    for i in [1, 0]
        let line = getline(range[i])
        if line =~ pat
            let line = substitute(line, pat, escape(mark[i], '\'), '')
        else
            let line .= printf(&commentstring, mark[i])
        endif
        call setline(range[i], line)
    endfor
endfunction
```

Both of the mappings follow the same routine.  Before adding starting and
ending folding markers, it checks separately whether the first and the last
lines of the block to fold match the `commentstring` pattern.  For each of the
two that do match, it inserts the corresponding marker inside the first found
comment, at the very beginning of its text.  Otherwise, the marker is
decorated according to the `commentstring` template and added at the end of
the line.

If in the latter case it is preferable to separate the marker on its own line,
one can change the for loop as shown below.

```
    for i in [1, 0]
        let line = getline(range[i])
        if line =~ pat
            let line = substitute(line, pat, escape(mark[i], '\'), '')
            call setline(range[i], line)
        else
            call append(range[i] - !i, printf(&commentstring, mark[i]))
        endif
    endfor
```

Unlike the previous version of the loop, the order of processing the two
lines is important: The ending marker line should be added first, if
necessary, because inserting a line for the beginning marker would shift the
following lines changing their numbers.

Comment: Very nice.  The only thing I would change is to use setline instead of append in the else clause to keep the marker on the same line.

Comment: @WilliamPursell:  I think, you are right: It is good idea to make this behavior default for the custom `zf` command, since it would comply the behavior of the built-in `zf`.  The answer is updated accordingly.